# adding generic classes to hashmap

Tags: java, android, generics

I've created a HashMap that holds the class of my abstract Model as the key and then an instance of the Model as the value. I can't seem to add to it though. It doesn't seem like Java is smart enough to realize that what i'm putting into the HashMap is in fact a subclass of a Model instance.

```
abstract public class EntityManager<AbstractModel> {

    @Inject
    protected static Injector injector;

    private HashMap<Class<? extends AbstractModel>, AbstractModel> models = new HashMap<Class<? extends AbstractModel>, AbstractModel>();

    public void register(final AbstractModel model) {

        models.put(model.getClass(), model); // <-- the problem 

    }

    public AbstractModel get(Class<? extends AbstractModel> Class) {

        AbstractModel model = models.get(Class);

        if (model == null) {

            throw new RuntimeException("Attempting to retrieve an unregistered model.");

        } else {

            return model;
        }
    }
}
```

IntelliJ is telling me it's trying to add `Class<? extends Object>` instead of `Class<? extends Model>`

Comment: Note: 1. you should use the interface, that is `Map`; 2. all classes are singletons, so you should be using an `IdentityHashMap`: `private Map<Class<? extends AbstractModel>, AbstractModel> models = new IdentityHashMap<Class<? extends AbstractModel>, AbstractModel>();`

Comment: What you're doing is almost exactly Guava's [`MutableClassToInstanceMap`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/MutableClassToInstanceMap.html).

Comment: This compiles fine: http://ideone.com/0QsACc What am I missing?

Comment: your example doesn't use generics

Comment: `Map<Class<? extends Number>, Number>` is a generic type - what else could be related?

Comment: my AbstractModel implementation is being passed in by a class that extends EntityManager.

Comment: Is it literally extending `EntityManager`, as in a raw type? That could be the culprit.

Comment: @David so, my answer is not really accurate then...

Answer (score 2):

The `.getClass()` method you use here is the one of `Object`. And [its documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#getClass%28%29) says what you should do here:

```
final Class<? extends AbstractModel> c = model.getClass();
models.put(c, model);
```

Comment: Two notes: see @joaonlima's answer, you can just cast (but I hate casts, so I try and avoid them when I can); also, see my comment to your question: all `Class` objects are singletons, which is why you can use an `IdentityHashMap` (see the javadoc for this particular map implementation).

Comment: noted. Thanks for that! i changed my code to use an IdentityHashMap. I didn't that existed.

Comment: `final Class<? extends AbstractModel> c = model.getClass();` won't compile.

Comment: What is the key difference here vs. what the OP is already doing?

Comment: I don't understand why this is necessary - This compiles with javac and Eclipse: http://ideone.com/0QsACc (don't have IntelliJ unfortunately but that should be pointing to either of those compilers)

Answer (score 0):

You can just cast the call:

```
models.put((Class<? extends AbstractModel>) model.getClass(), model);
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks to the answers and suggestions i ended up going with this

```
abstract public class EntityManager<AbstractModel> {

    @Inject
    protected static Injector injector;

    private Map<Class<? extends AbstractModel>, AbstractModel> map = new IdentityHashMap<Class<? extends AbstractModel>, AbstractModel>();

    public EntityManager(){
        setUp();
    }

    public void register(Class<? extends AbstractModel> clazz) {

        map.put(clazz, injector.getInstance(clazz));
    }

    public AbstractModel get(Class<? extends AbstractModel> clazz) {

        AbstractModel model = map.get(clazz);

        if (model == null) {

            throw new RuntimeException("Attempting to retrieve an unregistered model.");

        } else {

            return model;
        }
    }

    abstract void setUp();
}
```